# Can’t identify shower seal replacement part

Tags: shower, cleaning

I have a corner shower with glass on three sides in a house I recently purchased. I need to replace the pictured rubber pieces that sit in the track next to the glass (not on the door sides- see image of glass and track). The previous owner didn’t clean them and they have pink mold. I can’t for the life of me figure out what to order to replace these, and didn’t have any luck locating it at the hardware store. Does anyone know what these are called or have suggestions on what to replace it with?[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a softener at the bottom of a sliding door? Is it attached to the metal track on both sides of the sliding door to prevent it from rattling against the track? Is it instead a swinging door, with this rubber mounted as a softener for the closing door?

Comment: Can't you just remove, clean, and replace?

Comment: Not a promise, but it's worth looking for not just "shower door seal" on Ebay, but also "window rubber seal" and similar terms, as the same profiles are used for both. Some listings have many different types so you'll need to measure up

Answer (score 1):

Many glass doors and panels in showers are installed by local companies with proprietary frame materials.

The frames are extruded aluminum and the seals are designed to seal the glass to the frames.  Seals are not something common to all frames.

Your best bet is to contact a shower enclosure company. Either take the seal to them or ask for them to come to your home and evaluate what you need. Many companies will be able to source the seals or refer you to the companies that can. They will install for you as well if you cannot.